# PDF bookmarks don't get proper formatting

Tags: pdf, context, bookmarks

In my document, I have two chapter titles with `\em` commands and `---` dashes, which get correctly converted to *italics* and em-dash in the text. But the PDF bookmarks are not created properly:

- `\em`: if I use syntax `\em{text}`, bookmark is created with only text (as expected). If I use `{\em text}`, this entire string is used as-is in PDF bookmark.
- `---`: conversion to em-dash never occurs.

**How can I get `\em` and `---` properly in PDF bookmarks?** I don't need the bookmark gets styled. Below a code sample and screenshot (in SumatraPDF):

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\placebookmarks[chapter, section][chapter, section]
\setupinteractionscreen[option=bookmark]
\setuptagging[state=start]
\starttext
\chapter[title={{\em Chapter} --- a note}]

Some paragraph.

\section{{\em A year from monday} --- from John Cage}

Some paragraph.

\chapter[title={\em{Chapter} --- another note}]

Some paragraph.

\section{\em{Silence} --- from John Cage}

Some paragraph.

\stoptext
```

Screenshot (note bookmarks with `---` and `\em` appearing):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure if the PDF format even supports markup in bookmarks, but if you just want to get rid of the LaTeX commands there, use `\texorpdfstring{LaTeX document text}{PDF bookmarks text}` from the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @siracusa: I am no ConTeXt user, but I doubt that this format uses `hyperref` at all, but you're right about the possible issues with markup in `bookmark`. Only a few styles are possible for bookmark contents, such as bold  or color, and it depends on the pdf viewer if this markup is displayed correctly

Comment: It is either `{\em ...}` or `\emph{...}`.  In the second chapter you are using `\em{...}` which will have the wrong behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can choose between two styles, italic and bold, but they apply to the entry as a whole.  Also style and color are only available from PDF 1.4 onwards and marked optional, so support is probably limited to Adobe Reader.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I didn't want to style the bookmark itself. I just wanted to get a clean bookmark, without those `{\em ... }` parts. Sorry, I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oops, I missed that this is a ConTeXt question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand all macros in the bookmarks, you have to add

```
\enabledirectives[references.bookmarks.preroll]
```

in your document.  I don't think you can apply ligatures in the bookmarks, because ligatures are part of the font.  What you can do is, instead of `---` either use the Unicode character `—` (U+2014 EM DASH) directly or the corresponding control sequence `\emdash`.

Also, when you use tagging, I think you *have* to use the `\start...\stop` pairs for chapter, section, etc.  At least `pdfinfo` shows me wrong nesting if I don't use `\start...\stop`.

```
\enabledirectives[references.bookmarks.preroll]
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\placebookmarks[chapter, section][chapter, section]
\setupinteractionscreen[option=bookmark]
\setuptagging[state=start]

\starttext

\startchapter[title={{\em Chapter} — a note}]

  Some paragraph.

  \startsection[title={{\em A year from monday} — from John Cage}]

    Some paragraph.

  \stopsection

\stopchapter


\startchapter[title={\emph{Chapter} \emdash\ another note}]

  Some paragraph.

  \startsection[title={\emph{Silence} \emdash\ from John Cage}]

    Some paragraph.

  \stopsection

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

```
$ pdfinfo -struct-text test.pdf
Div
  Sect "chapter"
    Div
      H (block)
        "1"
      H (block)
        "Chapter— a note"
    Div
      "Some paragraph."
      Sect "section"
        Div
          H (block)
            "1.1"
          H (block)
            "A year from monday— from John Cage"
        Div
          "Some paragraph."
  Sect "chapter"
    Div
      H (block)
        "2"
      H (block)
        "Chapter— another note"
    Div
      "Some paragraph."
      Sect "section"
        Div
          H (block)
            "2.1"
          H (block)
            "Silence— from John Cage"
        Div
          "Some paragraph."
```

Comment: It works after using `\enabledirectives`! If I'm not wrong, `---` is not a font ligature, but a TeX ligature (enabled via `tlig`), so I thought it was a macro internally. Anyway, just `\em` is corrected; `---` still shows as three hyphens. But at least I can use the symbol directly, as you explained. Thank you!

Comment: @JosédeMattosNeto A ligature is a ligature and will only be applied when a font is rendered which will never take place for a bookmark.