# ConTeXt: Replace tokens in document title option

Tags: context, tilde, document-configuration

## Background

Macros are autogenerated for a book's title and author name. The title can sometimes include TeX-specific tokens, such as `~` and `ldots{}`.

## Problem

When setting the document properties, the title includes the verbatim values in the book title macro.

## Code

Consider:

```
\def\BookTitle{The Strange Case of Dr.~Jekyll and Mr.~Hyde}
\setupinteraction[title=\BookTitle,]
\starttext \input knuth \stoptext
```

Produces:

[image: Output]

## Question

How do you replace the tilde (and other possible entities) such that the typeset value (e.g., a non-breaking space) is passed to the `title` option of the `setupdocument` command?

The `\expandafter` macro doesn't seem to be the correct approach (also, there's no way to know how many items would need expanding). The `\detokenize` macro didn't seem to interpret the `~` token. Using `\the` and `\relax` broke the build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a builtin option for this.  Simply enable the directive `interaction.identity.preroll`.  The same preroll functionality is available for bookmarks with `references.bookmarks.preroll`, see also [PDF bookmarks don't get proper formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467474/pdf-bookmarks-dont-get-proper-formatting)

```
\enabledirectives[interaction.identity.preroll]
\def\BookTitle{The Strange Case of Dr.~Jekyll and Mr.~Hyde}
\setupinteraction[title=\BookTitle,]
\starttext \input knuth \stoptext
```

```
$ pdfinfo test.pdf | grep Title
Title:          The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde
```

Comment: @DaveJarvis There is a command line option to list all available directives and in principle their names should be self-documenting. Apart from that I don't think there is any docs.